# python scrapy : unable to login on website

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to login into a website with python script using the sample code given in Scrapy documentation. Here's the modified code:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request,FormRequest

class LoginSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'loginspidername'
    start_urls = ['http://example.com/index.php']
    login_page='http://example.com/index.php'

    def parse(self, response):
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'username': 'myname', 'Password': 'mypass'},
                    formxpath='//*[@id="loginblock"]/div/div/form',
                    callback=self.after_login)]

    def after_login(self, response):
        # check login succeed before going on
        if "logout" in response.body:
            print 'logged in'
        else:
            print 'not logged in'
        return
```

Also, here's the HTML section, in case required:

```
<div class="canvas" name="slideblock" id="loginblock" style="display: none;">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="loginFloater">
            <div align="right"><a href="javascript:hideDiv('loginblock');">close(X)</a></div>
            <h2>Login</h2>

            <form method="post" action="login.php">
            <label>Username</label><input class="data" name="username" value="" placeholder="username" type="text"><br>
            <label>Password</label><input class="data" name="password" value="" placeholder="password" type="password"><br>
            <label></label><strong style="display:none ">Wrong Password Try again</strong>
            <label>&nbsp;</label><input type="submit" class="searchButton" value="Login"></form>
            <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" value="true"> Remember Me<br><br>
            <label>&nbsp;</label><a href="#">Forgot</a> Password?
            Not a member? <a href="javascript:slideDiv('signupblock');">Signup</a> 
            <br>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The output is always 'not logged in'
As simple a code it may seem, it simply isn't logging in. I am unable to think of any possible issue in the code. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Comment: First of all, you're not sending **all** the input fields (for instance, the *rememberme* value is not sent with the login data. This is strict policy to send all the fields.

Comment: Corrected my code @Torxed but it still isn't working.

Comment: As mentioned below, you also have a typ-o, correct those things first because as i pointed out, you need to be VERY careful to details when doing stuff like this.. Very little programming skills have to be present in ancient web-development while attention to details is key.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a typo: `Password` should be `password`.

Comment: Corrected the typo, but it still doesn't seem to work. Thanks though.

Comment: In that case can you verify the site is doing a simple POST and not adding extra information through javascript? You can check this through chrome dev tools, look for the headers and post data.